# Android layout multiple screens - clarify me

Tags: android-layout

Lets say i have a layout with size 320x480px. The layout has a background, a menu background with 2 buttons and the logo.
What is the best way to support most devices?
I know i should have the assets for all the four densities.
I mean, after I read about the 3:4:6:8 scale ratio, in this case the background is 320x480 for a normal screen with mdpi. So for **hdpi** the background would have **480x720px (1.5x)**, for **xhdpi 640x960px (2.0x)**,
and **ldpi 240x360px (0.75x)**, is that correct?

Another thing is, can i have both qualifiers **res/drawable-xhdpi, /drawable-hdpi, /drawable-mdpi, /drawable-ldpi** and the **res/layout-small, /normal, /large, /xlarge**?

What it gets confusing me is, what if the user has a normal screen device hdpi, the background img used would be the one on drawable-hdpi, but its too large for a normal screen in this case the background size would be 480x720px , it isn't?

Please can someone give me a hand on this, im trying to help the developer with the layout xml and assets, but I can't understand it.

I think what i need to know is what is the most "common" screen size in pixels for low, normal, large, xlarge, but what about the densities?

I really appreciate if someone can clarify this for me!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a most "common" screen size with android.

You create your assets in different densities and scale them accordingly. All you have to do is using correct scale ratios for your assets and creating a density independent layout.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for an introduction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you give me some example?
I mean, how can i specify an image size for the layout if i dont have any dimensions to use as guide so i could place the image and see if its a good size?
Should i create an image for example 100x100px, use the multiplier 1.5x for hdpi (150x150), 2.0x for xhdpi(200x200), and 0.75x for ldpi(75x75), place each image on correspondent res/drawable folder, and lets say on the xml from layout/layout-large i should specify the width and height using dp? But doing that it wont be scaling it anyway?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: By choosing width and height in dp in your layout, the images will be scaled, except you set the dp according to your images - but usually it's the other way round.

You choose your initial picture size according to what "looks good" in your layout and depending what type of picture it is. It's perfectly normal to start with a standard size screen - e.g. from Galaxy SII - and design your layout. 
After that you try it with different resolutions and tune your layout and images.